# Can multiple application share same Lucene index?

Tags: c#, lucene

I am developing an application which will be used by 10 users.
I will use Lucene for better search perfomance.
Can I generate Lucene index files in the server and let 10 applications share that same Lucene index files?
Only one application will have write to update the index while other 9 applications are read-only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can **read** the same lucene index from different applications. If the applications are on the same JVM you could also share the same `IndexSearcher`, because the open/close of the index are quite costly. 
Anyhow, you could have only one instance of IndexSearcher for application.

Only one **client**/**application** can **write** the index **at the same time**, so you could write the index also from different application but you must synchronize the index management operations: open/write/close.